# TypeError: (0 , _htmlPdf.create)(...).foFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, html-pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file in nodejs using "html-pdf" package.

First I imported as `import pdf from "html-pdf"` and got this error:

 [_htmlPdf.default.create(...).foFile is not a function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lelat.png)

But when I imported `import { create } from "html-pdf"` I am getting this error in the console:

[TypeError: (0 , _htmlPdf.create)(...).foFile is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9FtU.png)

**This is the template I am using** (*Babel js is being used in nodejs*):

```
const labresult = (formData) => {
  const today = new Date();

  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>LabResult</title>

        <style>
          body {
            background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
          }
          page {
            background: white;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* border: 0.5rem outset black; */
            outline: 0.5rem solid black;
            /* outline: 0.8rem outset black; */
            outline-offset: -2rem;
            /* margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */
          }
          page[size='A4'] {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
          }
          h1,
          h2,
          h3,
          h4 {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #388fe3;
          }

          h1 {
            font-size: 2.7rem;
          }

          h2 {
            font-size: 2.3rem;
          }

          h3 {
            font-size: 2rem;
          }

          h4 {
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            color: #000;
          }

          th,
          td {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
          }

          p {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          }

          .outer {
            display: table;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
          }

          .middle {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }

          .inner {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 17cm;
            /* Whatever width you want */
          }
          table {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 1.5rem 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid #000;
          }
          td,
          th {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            font-size: 1.15rem;
          }

          th {
            text-align: start;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <page size="A4">
          <h2
            style="
              color: rgb(221, 82, 47);
              margin-top: 2cm;
              margin-left: 5cm;
              position: absolute;
              text-decoration: underline;
            "
          >
            Bahodir Shifo Diagnostika
          </h2>
          <p
            style="
              font-weight: bold;
              color: rgb(40, 214, 98);
              font-size: 2em;
              margin-left: 7cm;
              margin-top: 4cm;
              position: absolute;
            "
          >
            Диагностический центр
          </p>
          <div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 4.6cm; position: absolute; margin-left: 6.5cm; color: #388fe3">
            <p>г. Ташкент, Яшнабадский р-н, ул. Aвиасозлар, дом 56</p>
            <p style="position: relative; margin-top: -0.3cm; margin-left: 0.5cm">
              +99890 983 05 72 +99890 372 54 18 (Telegram)
            </p>
          </div>
          <div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 7cm; position: absolute; margin-left: 2cm; font-size: larger">
            <p>Дата исследования:</p>
            <p>Пациент:</p>
            <p>Ден рождения:</p>
          </div>
          <div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 7cm; position: absolute; margin-left: 10cm; font-size: larger">
            <p>10.11.2021</p>
            <p>Jon Snow</p>
            <p>11.12.1989</p>
          </div>
          <div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 11cm; position: absolute; margin-left: 2cm; font-size: larger">
            <table style="width: 17cm;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Наименование</th>
                  <th>Резултат</th>
                  <th>Норма</th>
                  <th>Ед. изм.</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 23cm; position: absolute; margin-left: 2cm; font-size: larger">
            <p>Интерпретация резултатов анализов толко за лечашим врачом!</p>
            <p style="color: #388fe3; position: relative; margin-top: -0.5cm">"BAHODIR SHIFO" Желайет Вам здоровя</p>
            <p style="color: #388fe3">В случаи утери документа копия не выдаеця</p>
            <p style="font-size: larger">Врач лаборант: Дехканова Г.М_______________</p>
          </div>
        </page>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};

export default labresult
```

**This is the route:**

```
import labresult from '../../utils/labresult';

router.post('/create-pdf', requireJwtAuth, (req, res) => {
  create(labresult(), {}).foFile('labresult.pdf', (err) => {
    console.log('API Call to create-pdf');
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to create pdf.' });
    }

    return res.status(200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

import labresult from '../../utils/labresult';

```
router.post('/create-pdf', requireJwtAuth, (req, res) => {
  create(labresult(), {}).toFile('labresult.pdf', (err) => {
    console.log('API Call to create-pdf');
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to create pdf.' });
    }

    return res.status(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: It was a typo. I used ".foFile() instead of ".toFile()". It was clear after a coffee break :)